# Classical book or jupyter notebooks?

Tags: references

I am working on a series of chapters for a book on Machine Learning, in particular on the mathematics behind it, but with clear references to how to implement it in Python (see vectorization for example). My question to the community is (and apologies if this is the wrong place): would you prefer a classical book (pdf) or a series of Jupyter notebooks with math, text and code in the same place that you can fork, study and use? The book would be mainly focusing on theory, although I will support it with several examples (see for example overfitting, or optimisation algorithms like Adam or Momentum).

Feedback would be much welcome, before I start (the huge) work on it.

Thanks in advance, Umberto

Answer (score 2):

For people who know how to edit text and implement code in Jupyter, what advantages would writing a Machine Learning textbook in a PDF file offer? Especially if the targeted consumer is assumed to be knowledgeable enough to have dealt with either Jupyter directly or just Python, I can't really see any benefits in PDF format other than conventionality (which is honestly quickly changing for books of this nature in this field).

Comment: I agree with you. Wanted just to check what the community was thinking. Thanks.